# Odoo 11 unable to create template DB in SaaS Plans

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, odoo, odoo-11, odoo-12

**Hello Readers,**

I am using Odoo 11 in ubuntu 16.04 trying to install Odoo SaaS tool kit 11 for Odoo v11 CE in my local machine and I am facing an issue when I create template DB in SaaS=> SaaS=> Plans It is showing the Following Exception:

```
    Error:
Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shivam/Documents/Odoo/odoo-11.0/odoo/http.py", line 651, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/home/shivam/Documents/Odoo/odoo-11.0/odoo/http.py", line 310, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/home/shivam/Documents/Odoo/odoo-11.0/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 87, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/shivam/Documents/Odoo/odoo-11.0/odoo/http.py", line 693, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/home/shivam/Documents/Odoo/odoo-11.0/odoo/http.py", line 342, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shivam/Documents/Odoo/odoo-11.0/odoo/service/model.py", line 97, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shivam/Documents/Odoo/odoo-11.0/odoo/http.py", line 335, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/shivam/Documents/Odoo/odoo-11.0/odoo/http.py", line 937, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/shivam/Documents/Odoo/odoo-11.0/odoo/http.py", line 515, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/shivam/Documents/Odoo/odoo-11.0/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 938, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
  File "/home/shivam/Documents/Odoo/odoo-11.0/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 926, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/shivam/Documents/Odoo/odoo-11.0/odoo/api.py", line 689, in call_kw
    return call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/shivam/Documents/Odoo/odoo-11.0/odoo/api.py", line 680, in call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shivam/Documents/Odoo/odoo-11.0/saas/saas_portal/models/saas_portal.py", line 410, in create_template_button
    return self.create_template()
  File "/home/shivam/Documents/Odoo/odoo-11.0/saas/saas_portal/models/saas_portal.py", line 432, in create_template
    (req.url, res.reason, res.content))
Warning: Error on request: http://s1.odoo.local:80/saas_server/new_database
Reason: NOT FOUND 
 Message: b'<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">\n<title>404 Not Found</title>\n<h1>Not Found</h1>\n<p>The requested URL was not found on the server.  If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>\n'
```

and I am following document [Odoo SaaS Tool Doc](https://odoo-saas-tools.readthedocs.io/en/10.0/setup/install.html) and my **etc/hosts** file is following:

> `127.0.0.1    localhost
>   127.0.1.1 shivam.sahu shivam
>
> ::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback fe00::0 ip6-localnet ff00::0
>   ip6-mcastprefix ff02::1 ip6-allnodes ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
>
> 127.0.0.1 odoo.local # portal
>   127.0.0.1 s1.odoo.local # server
>   127.0.0.1 t1.odoo.local # template
>   127.0.0.1 t2.odoo.local # template
>   127.0.0.1 client-x.odoo.local
>   127.0.0.1 client-y.odoo.local
>   127.0.0.1 client-z.odoo.local`

and my **/etc/nginx/sites-available/default** is following:

> `server { listen 80 default_server; proxy_set_header Host $host;
>   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; proxy_set_header
>   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; proxy_set_header
>   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
>
> location /longpolling { proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8072; }
>
> location / { proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8069; } }

my **/etc/odoo.conf** is following:

> [options]
>
> ; This is the password that allows database operations:
>
> ; admin_passwd = admin
>
> db_host = False
>
> db_port = False
>
> db_user = odoo
>
> db_password = False
>
> limit_time_cpu = 600
>
> limit_time_real = 1200
>
> workers = 3
>
> logfile = /var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log
>
> addons_path = /opt/odoo/addons,/opt/odoo/odoo/addons`

Please help me how I can resolve this exception.

Answer (score 1):

Some Confriguations are missed by me the and the missed configurations are the following: 
This my **etc/nginx/conf.d/server.conf**

```
server {
        server_name example.com *.example.com ;
        listen 80;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/testing-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/testing-error.log;
        location /longpolling {
            proxy_connect_timeout   3600;
            proxy_read_timeout      3600;
            proxy_send_timeout      3600;
            send_timeout            3600;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8072;
    }
        location / {
            proxy_connect_timeout   3600;
            proxy_read_timeout      3600;
            proxy_send_timeout      3600;
            send_timeout            3600;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8069/;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
        gzip on;
        gzip_min_length 1000;
    }
    upstream odoo {
    server 127.0.0.1:8069 weight=1 fail_timeout=0;
    }
    upstream odoo-im {
    server 127.0.0.1:8072 weight=1 fail_timeout=0;
    }
```

and this is my **etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   shivam.sahu shivam

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

127.0.0.1 odoo.local # portal

127.0.0.1 s1.odoo.local # server

127.0.0.1 t1.odoo.local # template

127.0.0.1 t2.odoo.local # template

127.0.0.1 client-x.odoo.local

127.0.0.1 client-y.odoo.local

127.0.0.1 client-z.odoo.local
```

and this my Odoo server file **etc/odoo.conf**

```
[options]
dbfilter = ^%h$
xmlrpc_port = 8069
longpolling_port = 8072
db_name = False
db_user = odoo
db_password = False
db_host = False
db_port = 5432
logfile = /var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log
```

After that creating 2 databases **odoo.local** and **s1.odoo.local** and installed in  saas portal *  and saas server in that I browse the link **www.odoo.local:8069/web/login** for accessing odoo.local database and after that, I follow the documentation [Odoo SaaS TooT Kit Doc](https://odoo-saas-tools.readthedocs.io/en/10.0/setup/install.html)

I hope this article help to install Odoo Saas Toot kit for Odoo v11

Thankyou.